# How to change the variable of agents that I filtered using sortAscending in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent population of 100. The population has a parameter called budget which has a value between 100 to 200.

Now I sorted this population and filtered out the 1st 3 agents with the maximum budget using the following function on the startup function of Main agent.

```
List ags =sortAscending(main.bidders,m->m.Budget).subList(0,1);
for(Bidder m : main.bidders){
    m.willDoSomething=true;
}
```

Now, next i want to change the value of a variable of type boolean to true for those three agents only. But the above code, changes the variable to true for all agents. I dont know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List ags =sortAscending(main.bidders,m->m.Budget).subList(0,1);
for(Bidder m : ags){
    m.willDoSomething=true;
}
```

the for loop changed main.biders with ags

Comment: Hello, this returns the following error "Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Bidder. Location: WindEnergyBid/Bidder - Agent Type"